# Need a Ruby method to convert a binary array to ASCII alpha-numeric string

Tags: ruby

I have an array of `[1, 0, 11, 0, 4, 0, 106, 211, 169, 1, 0, 12, 0, 8, 0, 1, 26, 25, 32, 189, 77, 216, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 15]`.

I would love to create a string version mostly for logging purposes. My end result would be `"01000B0004006AD3..."`

I could not find a simple way to take each array byte value and pack a string with an ASCII presentation of the byte value.

My solution is cumbersome. I appreciate advice on making the solution slick.

```
array.each {|x| 
  value = (x>>4)&0x0f 
  if( value>9 ) then
    result_string.concat (value-0x0a + 'A'.ord).chr
  else
    result_string.concat (value + '0'.ord).chr
  end
  value = (x)&0x0f 
  if( value>9 ) then
    result_string.concat (value-0x0a + 'A'.ord).chr
  else
    result_string.concat (value + '0'.ord).chr
  end
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear, but I guess something like this is what you are looking for:

```
array.map {|n| n.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0').upcase }.join
#=> "01000B0004006AD3A901000C000800011A1920BD4DD80100010004000000000C0F"
```

or

```
array.map(&'%02X'.method(:%)).join
#=> "01000B0004006AD3A901000C000800011A1920BD4DD80100010004000000000C0F"
```

Which one of the two is more readable depends on how familiar your readers are with `sprintf`-style format strings, I guess.

Comment: sick ruby skills wrt `&'%02X'.method(:%)`

Comment: Thank you @Jörg W Mittag

Answer (score 2):

It's actually pretty simple:

```
def hexpack(data)
  data.pack('C*').unpack('H*')[0]
end
```

That packs your bytes using integer values (`C`) and unpacks the resulting string to hex (`H`). In practice:

```
hexpack([1, 0, 11, 0, 4, 0, 106, 211, 169, 1, 0, 12, 0, 8, 0, 1, 26, 25, 32, 189, 77, 216, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 15])
# => "01000b0004006ad3a901000c000800011a1920bd4dd80100010004000000000c0f"
```

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest you stick to hex or base64 instead of making your own formatting

```
dat = [1, 0, 11, 0, 4, 0, 106, 211, 169, 1, 0, 12, 0, 8, 0, 1, 26, 25, 32, 189, 77, 216, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 15]
```

Hexadecimal

```
hex = dat.map { |x| sprintf('%02x', x) }.join
# => 01000b0004006ad3a901000c000800011a1920bd4dd80100010004000000000c0f
```

Base64

```
require 'base64'
base64 = Base64.encode64(dat.pack('c*'))
# => AQALAAQAatOpAQAMAAgAARoZIL1N2AEAAQAEAAAAAAwP\n
```

---

**Proquints**

What? [Proquints](https://arxiv.org/html/0901.4016) are pronounceable unique identifiers which makes them great for reading/communicating binary data. In your case, maybe not the best because you're dealing with 30+ bytes here, but they're very suitable for smaller byte strings

```
# proquint.rb
# adapted to ruby from https://github.com/deoxxa/proquint
module Proquint
  C = %w(b d f g h j k l m n p r s t v z)
  V = %w(a i o u)

  def self.encode (bytes)
    bytes << 0 if bytes.size & 1 == 1
    bytes.pack('c*').unpack('S*').reduce([]) do |acc, n|
      c1 = n         & 0x0f
      v1 = (n >> 4)  & 0x03
      c2 = (n >> 6)  & 0x0f
      v2 = (n >> 10) & 0x03
      c3 = (n >> 12) & 0x0f
      acc << C[c1] + V[v1] + C[c2] + V[v2] + C[c3]
    end.join('-')
  end

  def decode str
    # learner's exercise
    # or see some proquint library (eg) https://github.com/deoxxa/proquint
  end
end

Proquint.encode dat
# => dabab-rabab-habab-potat-nokab-babub-babob-bahab-pihod-bohur-tadot-dabab-dabab-habab-babab-babub-zabab
```

Of course the entire process is reversible too. You might not need it, so I'll leave it as an exercise for the learner

It's particularly nice for things like IP address, or any other short binary blobs. You gain familiarity too as you see common byte strings in their proquint form

```
Proquint.encode [192, 168, 11, 51] # bagop-rasag
Proquint.encode [192, 168, 11, 52] # bagop-rabig
Proquint.encode [192, 168, 11, 66] # bagop-ramah
Proquint.encode [192, 168, 22, 19] # bagop-kisad
Proquint.encode [192, 168, 22, 20] # bagop-kibid
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I totally spaced sprintf:) Exactly what I was after!

Comment: Roman, I added another answer that might surprise you. Let me know if it helps ^_^

Comment: I love this. It is taking me time to digest. I came back to using ruby and am loving it:)

Comment: This is pretty cool:) I am using mac - 6 byte values all the time and had few mispronounced or misread problems. I will try Proquint instead.

Comment: ^_^ proquint works nicely for any 16-bit value. The function above will automatically pad the bytes if an odd number is given